# Set timeout for specific call

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit and OkHttp for my Android app.

I followed [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-creating-a-sustainable-android-client) to create a class to handle the API client:

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://www.website.com/api/";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .baseUrl(API_URL);

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor logging =
            new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                    .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return retrofit;
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, Context context) {
        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(logging)) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        }

        builder.client(httpClient.build());
        retrofit = builder.build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

}
```

And here is how I call the client in various parts of my app:

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class, context);

Call<BasicResponse> call = apiService.uploadImage();
call.enqueue(new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<BasicResponse> call, Response<BasicResponse> response) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<BasicResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        //
    }
});
```

However, my app has an image upload feature that allows users to upload images to the server. OkHttp's default timeout is set to something between 10-20 seconds and this isn't long enough as it causes a timeout error if the image takes too long to upload.

Because of this, I want to increase the timeout for *this call only*.

How can I add a method in my `ApiClient` class to set a timeout for a specific call and be able to do something like:

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class, context);

// Add this
apiService.setTimeout(100 seconds);

Call<BasicResponse> call = apiService.uploadImage();
call.enqueue(new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<BasicResponse> call, Response<BasicResponse> response) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<BasicResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        //
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this only seems to be possible by creating two separate Retrofit services, with two different `OkHttp` instances. One instance would have the default timeout, one would have the extended timeout configured.

Comment: Will be simpler in an upcoming release once we’ve implemented [better interceptor chains](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3039).